# Probability of choosing a green marble if a brown marble was transferred

Tags: probability

Box A contains 4 green and 5 brown marbles. Box B contains 6 green and 8 brown marbles. A marble is chosen from Box A and placed in Box B, then a marble is drawn from Box B.

(a) What is the probability the second marble chosen in green?
(b) If the second marble chosen is green, what is the probability a brown marble was transferred?

I think I understand part a, and here is what I did:

There are 2 cases:

case 1: Pr(first marble chosen is green) * Pr(second marble chosen is green). So, 4/9 * 7/9 = 28/135.

case 2: Pr(first marble chosen is brown) * Pr(second marble chosen is green).
So, 5/9 * 6/15 = 2/9.

Then 28/135 + 2/9 = 58/135 = Pr(2nd marble is green)

For part B, I know that I have to do Bayes Theorem, but I am not quite sure how to set it up.

Comment: Why $7/9$? Did you mean $7/15$?

Answer (score 1):

Let's give names to the events.

Event A: Second marble chosen is green

Event B: Brown marble transferred

Just apply Bayes' rule:
$P(B|A) = \dfrac{P(A|B)P(B)}{P(A)}$

$P(A|B) = 6/15$

$P(A) = 58/135$

$P(B) = 5/9$